# Does multi-frequency GPS help during cloudy/overcast skies?

Tags: gps, garmin

One of the problems with GPS is difficulty locking on to a signal when the device is under dense canopy or when the skies are overcast.

Do multi-frequency (not multi-GNSS) GPS systems help with this? Does communicating over 2 different frequencies make it easier to establish a connection when the path to the satellite is obstructed?

Comment: Could you share the model you have?

Comment: None yet. Just going mad with pre purchase research. It is afterall a long term purchase for a significant amount of money. More importantly, the right feature, if used right, can be life saving. So need to understand the use case of the new tech. Since you asked, I'm looking at Garmin GPSMap devices and also wrist watches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, satellite signal (for GPS) do penetrate through the clouds with no issues. GPS signal can go through weather conditions. More reading is available from this site:http://gpsinformation.net/gpsclouds.htm .

However, you are right the trees cover affect  the signal as it bounces against the trees.

Multi frequency GPS could help in getting a fix and a good accuracy faster. Meaning the more GPS you have in the , however if you are working under a thick canopy that would affect your signal and using a surveyor might be a better choice.  What we used to do however, was to hook an external antenna and attach it to a long flexible stick, it helped from time to time.

Comment: So basically, it helps with canopy but weather doesn't matter. Right? From the link you shared: Just a few millimeters of  "solid" water will severely attenuate the GPS signal. Does this mean multi frequency won't help in this scenario, since all frequencies are severely hampered anyways?

Comment: We will still get some signal under canopy but week and not accurate. The example about the water on the windshield, they say it does not affect it, it is because of the wiper that there is interference. Whatever it is, depending on your GPS model you should be able to hook in an external antenna directly. If not search for a re-transmitting or re-radiating antenna.